# Building Shape Model

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition, menpo

I am trying to build Statistical Shape Model(I want to start with Statistical Shape Model and then I will try to build Active Shape Model and Active Appearance Model).

So I implemented two classes, first for Generalized Procrustes Analysis([Python code sample which I translated to C# code](https://github.com/catchagain/procrupy/blob/master/procrupy/procrupy.py)) and second for Principal Component Analysis([C# code sample](http://crsouza.com/2009/10/principal-component-analysis-in-c/)).

I have [one more sample](https://github.com/menpo/menpofit/blob/master/menpofit/builder.py) which has function which can build shape model, but I can't use it because it is very difficult to understand. That function also uses GPA and PCA but returns different result.
So my questions:

1. Why results are different(given that my code gives the same results as in the samples)?
2. How I can connect(if I may say so) these two classes and what else I need to do to build shape model?

Any help would be useful! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm one of the menpo developers. How is your result different? Have you viewed the eigenvectors of your shape model to see if it looks sensible?